# Does Elasticsearch score different length shingles with the same IDF?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, lucene, elasticsearch-5, relevance

In Elasticsearch 5.6.5 I'm searching against a field with the following filter applied:

```
"filter_shingle":{  
   "max_shingle_size":"4",
   "min_shingle_size":"2",
   "output_unigrams":"true",
   "type":"shingle"
}
```

When I perform a search for `depreciation tax` against a document with that exact text, I see the following explanation of the score:

```
weight(Synonym(content:depreciation content:depreciation tax)) .... [7.65]
weight(content:tax) ... [6.02]
```

If I change the search to `depreciation taffy` against the exact same document with `depreciation tax` in the content I get this explanation:

```
weight(Synonym(content:depreciation content:depreciation taffy)) .... [7.64]
```

This is not what I expected. I thought a match on the bigram token for `depreciation tax` would get a much higher score than a match on the unigram `depreciation`. However this scoring seems to reflect a simple unigram match. There is an extremely small difference and digging further this is because the `termFreq=28` under the `depreciation taffy` match, and `termFreq=29` under the `depreciation tax` match. I'm also not sure how this relates as I imagine across the shard holding this document there are very different counts for `depreciation`, `depreciation tax` and `depreciation tafffy`

Is this expected behavior? Is ES treating all the different sized shingles, including unigrams, with the same IDF value? Do I need to split out each shingle size into different sub fields with different analyzers to get the behavior I expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** 
Shingles and Synonyms are broken in Elastic/Lucene and a lot of hacks need to be applied until a fix is released (accurate as of ES 6).

1. Put unigrams, bigrams and so on in individual subfields and search them separately, combining the scores for an overall match. Don't use a single shingle filter on a field that does multiple n-gram configurations
2. Don't combine a synonym and shingle filter on the same field.

In my case I do a `must` match with synonyms on a unigram field, then a series of should matches to boost the score on shingles of each size, without synonyms

**Details**

I got an answer on the elastic support forums:
    https://discuss.elastic.co/t/does-elasticsearch-score-different-length-shingles-with-the-same-idf/126653/2

> Yep, this is mostly expected.
>
> It's not really the shingles causing the scoring oddness, but the fact
>   that SynonymQueries do the frequency blending behavior that you're
>   seeing. They use frequency of the original token for all the
>   subsequent 'synonym' tokens, as a way to help prevent skewing the
>   score results. Synonyms are often relatively rare, and would
>   drastically affect the scoring if they each used their individual
>   df's.
>
> From the Lucene docs:
>
> For scoring purposes, this query tries to score the terms as if you
>   had indexed them as one term: it will match any of the terms but only
>   invoke the similarity a single time, scoring the sum of all term
>   frequencies for the document.
>
> The SynonymQuery also sets the docFrequency to the maximum
>   docFrequency of the terms in the document. So for example, if:
>
> "deprecation"df == 5 "deprecation tax"df == 2, "deprecation taffy"df
>   == 1, it will use 5 as the docFrequency for scoring purposes.
>
> The bigger issue is that Lucene doesn't have a way to differentiate
>   shingles from synonyms... they both use tokens that overlap the
>   position of other tokens in the token stream. So if unigrams are mixed
>   with bi-(or larger)-grams, Lucene is tricked into thinking it's
>   actually a synonym situation.
>
> The fix is to keep your unigrams and bi-plus-grams in different
>   fields. That way Lucene won't attempt to use SynonymQueries in these
>   situations, because the positions won't be overlapping anymore.

Here's another related question that I asked which relates to how actual synonyms also get mangled when combined with shingles. https://discuss.elastic.co/t/es-5-4-synonyms-and-shingles-dont-seem-to-work-together/127552

Elastic/Lucene expands the synonym set, injects them into the token stream, then creates shingles. E.g. Query: `econ supply and demand => econ, economics, supply, demand`. Document: `... econ foo ... =>  econ, foo '. Now we get the shingle from the query "econ economics" and somehow this matches the document. No idea why since I only applied synonyms to the query, not the document, so I don't see the match. Also, the way the shingles are created from the query is wrong too.

> This is a [known problem](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-3475), and it is still not fully resolved. A number
>   of Lucene filters can't consume graphs as their inputs.
>
> There is currently active work being done on developing a [fixed
>   shingle filter](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-8202), and also an idea to have a sub-field for indexing
>   shingles.